# El modelo viene nulo en la parte post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hice un tutorial basándome en un vídeo y funciona bien, crea el rol. Intenté agregar yo la parte de borrar, sin embargo en la parte post el valor que recibe me aparece nulo.

Controlador Manage de Identity

```
[Authorize]
    public class ManageController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

        public ManageController()
        {
        }

        public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
            RoleManager = roleManager;
        }

// GET:
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRole(string id)
        {
            string nombre = string.Empty;

            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (elRol != null)
            {
                nombre = elRol.Name;
            }

            //Creas el ViewModel que espera la vista..
            RoleViewModel rvm = new RoleViewModel();
            //Le seteas las propiedades
            rvm.Name = nombre;
            //Retornas el ViewModel.
            return View(rvm);
        }         

        // POST:
        [HttpPost]        
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRoleAction(RoleViewModel rvm)
        {
            var nombre = rvm.Name;
            if (nombre != null)
            {
                var elRol = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(nombre);                

                if (elRol != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult roleRsult = RoleManager.DeleteAsync(elRol).Result;
                    if (roleRsult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Roles");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View("Error");
        }
```

Startup.Auth

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure el contexto de base de datos, el administrador de usuarios y el administrador de inicios de sesión para usar una única instancia por solicitud
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Vista Roles

```
@model IEnumerable<PruebaHG.Models.RoleViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
}

<h2>Roles</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateRole")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)                        
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)                
            </td>
            <td>
                @*Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRole", new { aRole = Model}) |*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRole", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteRole", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Vista DeleteRole

```
@model PruebaHG.Models.RoleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteRole";
}

<h2>DeleteRole</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>RoleViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteRoleAction", "Manage", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Roles")
        </div>
    }
```

Escojo el rol a borrar y le doy al botón, en el break point de la parte post, veo que el valor que recibe está nulo.

¿Será que estoy cometiendo un error en la forma en que puse la parte post?

Hice un paso a paso y el rvm de la parte get funciona correctamente.

Comment: Has dejado mucho código, pero no la parte relevante, a simple vista, la excepción se dispara porque  `_roleManager` es `null`, cuando puedas, edita la pregunta y agrega cómo definís esa variable, esa va a ser la fuente de tu problema

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar el error que te tira el compilador para saber que estás haciendo mal. Si no te tira ningún error tal vez el problema esté en la forma en que estás eliminando el registro.

Comment: Hice los cambios que me sugirieron, ahora creo que la pregunta queda más clara. @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema puede estar en la inyección de dependencias a la hora de crear el controlador, ya que no le estas asignando valores a las variables declaradas al principio. Prueba lo siguiente.

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;    

        //Este constructor vacio lo puedes eliminar
        public ManageController()
        {
        }

        public ManageController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }



        // POST:
        [HttpPost]        
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRoleAction(RoleViewModel rvm)
        {
            var nombre = rvm.Name;
            if (nombre != null)
            {
                var elRol = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(nombre);                

                if (elRol != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult roleRsult = _roleManager.DeleteAsync(elRol).Result;
                    if (roleRsult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Roles");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View("Error");
        }
```

otra cosa, tu vista esta basada en un modelo, en este caso RoleViewModel, sin embargo tu formulario no tiene ningun input para las propiedades de este modelo, solo tienes un input de tipo submit, por lo que en teoria no estás pasando nada al controlador.

Comment: ¿Qué cambios debería hacer @VicenteAlmea ?